# How to connect Azure with Google Cloud

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, azure-deployment

I am working on a final project in my school and there are a lot of new things to discover. We will make an API that will use Google Cloud APIs and deployment to Azure.

I have not gotten anywhere just googling this, it looks like everyone just uses one service or another but not together.

I have a basic .net Core API program with the initial controller, ValuesController.  After getting the ServiceKey from Google Cloud, I used one of their basic tutorial code for calling the Vision API with an image.  My problem is that everything works on localhost but after deploying the site to Azure and calling that controller in the browser,  Azure site always gives me 500 internal server error:

**Failed to load resource: 
the server responded with a status of 500 
(Internal Server Error).**

I tried to setup a debug for Azure but with no success.

```
 `[Route("api/sleepy")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
   // GET api/values
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
   {
       List<String> da = new List<String>();
       var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
       var image = Image.FromFile("shit.png");
       var response = client.DetectLabels(image);
       foreach (var annotation in response)
       {
           if (annotation.Description != null)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
               da.Add(annotation.Description);
            }
        }

        foreach (var stuff in da)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stuff);
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);


        return Ok(da);
    } `
```

When I just return a string or something else from my GET in ValueController,  that works on the Azure site,  I do not understand this problem of mine,  localhost gets the right information but something is missing since it does not work on the Azure deployed site.

The site i have been trying this with is:
https://webapplication220190211113216.azurewebsites.net/api/sleepy. It is just temporary to test this. THe image shit.png is a picture of a dog and located in the root of the project.

What am i missing here?  I would be very greatful if someone could at least guide me in the right directions, I have found no answers on google. :)

EDIT:
I managed to find a workaround by using regular Http requests,  it would still be interesting to hear the reasons for why using the client libraries result in 500 error on Azure.  :)

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you don't have the service credentials present and configured on the Azure machine. For Noda Time, I use Azure Key Vault to keep an encrypted copy of the service account JSON file, and load that on startup. An alternative would be to deploy the JSON file with the application, and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point to it. Another possibility is that the current working directory isn't at the root of the project. It would be worth turning more logging/diagnostics on so you could see what exception is being thrown.

Comment: Thank you, this is something we are trying to find out now along with other Azure related problems, at least i know where to look when we get to this problem again.